# Coursera Learn AngularJS Week 3 Exercise 4 Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The short story:
When I open up the index page using `gulp watch`, I see nothing.

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=confusionApp&p1=Er…0(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fscripts%2Fmain-94e7868a45.js%3A1%3A18165)
```

When I hit the link to see what the error is, it says that:

```
Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:
{1}
```

It then goes into ngRoute issues which I'm not using at this point, as I am using angular-ui-router.

I can't go any further without solving this problem so I'm throwing it up to you guys.

The code is below, but bear in mind,I am only including the areas I have changed in the assignment as it would be too long for this post. So if there's any other code you'd like to see, please put them into the contents.

Thanks.

header.html

```
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a ui-sref="app">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.aboutus">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.menu">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span>
                     Menu</a></li>
     <li><a ui-sref="app.contactus">
         <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

footer.html

```
...
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a ui-sref="app">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.aboutus">About</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.menu">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.contactus">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp',['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider){
        $stateProvider

            //route for the home page
            .state('app', {
                url:'/',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
                    },
                    'content': {
                        template: '<h1>To be completed</h1>',
                        controller: 'IndexController'
                    },
                    'footer': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
                    }
                }
            })

            //route to aboutus page
            .state('app.aboutus', {
                url:'aboutus',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        template: '<h1>To be completed</h1>',
                        controller: 'AboutController'
                    }
                }
            })

            //route to contactus page
            .state('app.contactus', {
                url:'contactus',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/contactus.html',
                        controller: 'ContactController'
                    }
                }
            })

            //route to menu page
            .state('app.menu', {
                url:'menu',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/menu.html',
                        controller: 'MenuController'
                    }
                }
            })

            //route to dishdetail page
            .state('app.dishdetail', {
                url:'menu/:id',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/dishdetail.html',
                        controller: 'DishDetailController'
                    }
                }
            });

            $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/');
    })

;
```

menu.html

```
...
<div class="media-left media-middle">
    <a ui-sref="app.dishdetail({id: dish._id})">
       <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}} />
    </a>
</div>
...
```

index.html

```
<body>

    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>


<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded the new app.js file, it fixed everything, but there wasn't that much different between the two files. (Much frustration.)

The templates were replaced with templateUrls which I had actually done and everything was the same, but when I just copied and pasted the code over my code, it worked.

Here is the new working code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            // route for the home page
            .state('app', {
                url:'/',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/header.html',
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
                        controller  : 'IndexController'
                    },
                    'footer': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/footer.html',
                    }
                }

            })

            // route for the aboutus page
            .state('app.aboutus', {
                url:'aboutus',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/aboutus.html',
                        controller  : 'AboutController'
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the contactus page
            .state('app.contactus', {
                url:'contactus',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/contactus.html',
                        controller  : 'ContactController'
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the menu page
            .state('app.menu', {
                url: 'menu',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/menu.html',
                        controller  : 'MenuController'
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the dishdetail page
            .state('app.dishdetails', {
                url: 'menu/:id',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/dishdetail.html',
                        controller  : 'DishDetailController'
                   }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    })
;
```

And if you are facing the same issue with the same course, then please copy and paste the app.js code even if you've filled everything in correctly.